# How to refresh an angular page with router without window.location.reaload?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular-routing, angular-router

I have the following approach for reset values in a component page. The page "new-edition" will be reset all the values in the component, navigating to another component ("my-editions") then navigate to the original location "new-edition". But I want to know if exists another way to do this, windows.location.reload() is not an option because the routing is configured to reloate to "parent-app".

```
confirmReset() {
   this.confirmationService.confirm({
     message: 'Do you want to reset?',
     header: 'Reset',
     accept: () => {
        // window.location.reload();
        this.router.navigate(['/parent-app/my-editions']);
        this.router.navigate(['/parent-app/new-edition']);
        this.router.nav
     },
   reject: () => {}
  });
}
```

Comment: Needs more information. Where are the values being stored? I would assume they are stored as variables in the component class, in which case changing the value of those variables to some default value could be exactly what you want.

Comment: see [this](https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2)

Answer (score 2):

You're not forced to reload whole page. It's better to create a resetter that will clear the component properly.

For example, if you have a form in your component you can [reset](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#reset) the whole form with [`this.form.reset();`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#reset), etc.

For example, you can create a `reset()` method in your component (that you can also call into your component `ngOnDestroy()` that will completely reset forms, variables and [unsubscribe observables](http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/).

Reload the whole app is a quite violent thing, resetting values with a message (a [toastr](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr) or anything else) is much more adapted.